# Two-column cell list (Drop Down List) - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I need a Two-Column cell list (Drop Down List).

By default, we can only see single column of value in the cell list using the Data Validation option but I want to populate the list from two different columns. Please have a look at Example Table bellow...

```
Example Table:
| Column A   |     Column B   |
-------------------------------
| Sr. 1      | Product One    |
| Sr. 2      | Product Two    |
| Sr. 3      | Product Three  |

Now cell list be like;
​Sr.1 - Product One
Sr.2 - Product Two
Sr.3 - Product Three​
```

I want a single formula approach without using any tricks if possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want a single formula approach without using any tricks if possible...

Because when using a formula `Data validation` does not allow an option for `Show dropdown list in cell` you will need a helper column with the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(A2:A4&" - "&B2:B4)
```

[image]

***Notes***
***The helper column could be anywhere in the sheet as well as hidden.***
*Please adjust ranges to your needs.*

Comment: I knew about this trick but didn't want to use it. Well, thanks for your time...